# Can I change the javascript code inside an iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have an iframe which loads a javascript tracking code. For analytics purposes it has to reside on another affiliate site which is not on the same domain.

```
<frame src="http://affiliate-site.com/sale-tracking/" name="frame" scrolling="no" id="frame">
</frame>
```

It is possible to change the value of a javascript variable using onload event? Or maybe something else?

```
// on the affiliate site page
var toBeChangedFromOutsideTheFrame = 0;
```

Comment: If it's cross domain, probably not !

Comment: yes it is cross domain

Comment: If it's on the same top level domain, and both sides set `document.domain`, then yes.  If not, then you (and the other side) will need to look into the [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) functionality.

Comment: thanks! I will edit to mention that is on a different domain

Comment: Given that the answer then is to use `postMessage`, ideally you need to go and investigate that yourself, and if you get stuck come back with a specific question, otherwise it's either too broad, or looking for a `postMessage` tutorial, which is off topic.

Comment: Thanks @JamesThorpe I will take a look on this, I had no idea where to start on